# How can I make a unicode title in LibGDX game?

Tags: java, utf-8, libgdx, internationalization

I have a game with Vietnamese title. To display the title I did like this:

```java
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
//config width, height, etc.
config.title = "Nhặt rác cùng ong";
new LwjglApplication(new GarbageCollector(), config);
```

Result:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/m13URMN.png]

Comment: Found this link: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization